# migrate file timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I have two migration files:

```
20110414132423_insert_bulk_data.rb #1st
20111122105951_add_some_columns.rb #2nd
```

and I run `rake db:migrate`, is the **1st** one run firstly since it has older timestamp??

Since I am in the middle of someone else's code, he made the `20110414132423_insert_bulk_data` migration which insert data to table, **but** this migration file complains an **unknown column in the table**, then I found the missing column is defined in the **2nd** `20111122105951_add_some_columns.rb`  migration file which has newer timestamp...

**How can I get rid of this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly, yes. The timestamp is used to order migrations and to navigate between them. See more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

1. delete this migrations
2. generate two new migrations in the way you need to run

Comment: In Rails concept, is the migration file with older timestamp run first ?